# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity API 17

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, numberformatexception

I've just a simple question.

I'm working on my project here on android and when i try it on my samsung s5 mini everythings is ok i'm getting no error at all. Results are sended back to my first activity.

But when i try to run my project on my old galaxy s2 i'm facing this error

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity 

    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
    ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { 
    cmp=com.pullups.thomas.pullup/.Workout (has extras) }} to activity 
    {com.pullups.thomas.pullup/com.pullups.thomas.pullup.Workout}: 
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
```

Can somebody tell my why it's working perfectly with my galaxy s5 mini but not with my galaxy s2.

s5 mini runs on 4.4.2
galaxy s2 runs on 4.2.2

Comment: It's very clear - `Invalid int: ""` you are trying to convert an empty string to an int somewhere.

Comment: can you post your code? It seems to me that you are receiving something in `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` method where `int = ""`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of my Second activity (the one who is sending the result) i get the extra and when the user click on the button i add +1 to compteurTimer and send it back to the first activity so it's clearly not an empty int because at least 1 is the default value

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    compteurTimer = intent.getExtras().getInt("compteurEntrainement",1);

    btn_passer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent workout = new Intent(CountDown.this, Workout.class);
            MyCount_DownTimer.cancel();

            compteurTimer++;

            workout.putExtra("compteurTimer", compteurTimer);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, workout);

            finish();
           }
    });
```

Then in first Activity i've got onActivity result code

```
        @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null ) {

        compteurEntrainement = data.getIntExtra("compteurTimer", 1);

        switch (compteurEntrainement){
            case 2:
                backColorDisplay(viewSerie2, viewSerie1, tabOfSeries[1]);
                break;
            case 3:
                backColorDisplay(viewSerie3, viewSerie2,tabOfSeries[2]);
                break;
            case 4:
                backColorDisplay(viewSerie4, viewSerie3,tabOfSeries[3]);
                break;
            case 5:
                backColorDisplay(viewSerie5, viewSerie4,tabOfSeries[4]);

                btnComplet.setText("TERMINÉ");
                btnComplet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        final Intent pre_workout = new Intent(Workout.this, Pre_Workout.class);

                        setResult(RESULT_OK, pre_workout);

                        finish();
                    }//onClick
                });
                break;
            default:
                viewSerieEnCours.setText(viewSerie1.getText().toString());
                break;
        }//switch
    }//if
}//onActivityResult
```

the question i'm asking is, why this code run with no error on my s5 mini but doesn't work on my galaxy s2.

For now i've added this to my first activity

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

And after this i've got no error but the compteurTimer is not incrementing itself so i'm stucked

Answer (score 0):

few hints:

You can use parameter less constructor for result `Intent`:

Intent data = new Intent();
 /// data.....
 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
 finish();

no need to set explicitly which activity to use as delivery.

Also make sure you are not calling finish in some other place, like in this `MyCount_DownTimer`.

Make sure that in line: `workout.putExtra("compteurTimer", compteurTimer);`, `compteurTimer` is acutally of `int` type.